# open multiple links with window.open

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I'm trying to make something like when the link is opened, open multiple links at once **include current page**. so this is how I made in javascript below. Can you guys suggest any improvement about this code?

```
for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
        if(i === links.length-1) {
          window.open(links[i], "_self");
        } else { 
          window.open(links[i], "_blank");
        }
```

Comment: Does your existing code work? This is the sort of thing that popup blockers were created to prevent.

Comment: @nnnnnn I tested it with my friends computer and my computer. In my computer It worked successfully but in my friend's computer It opened only one link. so I want to fix it but I can't find what is the problem

Comment: @nnnnnn oh I just found the problem you were right. then how can I make it worked?

Comment: Different browsers have different options that the *user* can set to control whether popups are blocked. As far as I know (and hope) you can't do anything from your JS to override this.

Comment: @nnnnnn Is there any tricks to avoid it?

Comment: can you put hidden links and then on page load click on them?

Comment: or any other events?

Comment: i mean click by javascript

Comment: @Araz I tried it but it blocked by popup blockers too. omg